# Citing two different lemmas from the same source at once

Tags: citing

This is a stylistic question.

I am writing my thesis. At one point I want to quote two different lemmas from the same book.

Which of the following two is better or more appropriate etc.?

```
(1) ...; see [9, Lemma 8.3] and [9, Lemma 8.4].

(2) ...; see [9, Lemma 8.3, Lemma 8.4].
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if a stylistic question is on topic here or would be better at Academy.SE.  But I'd prefer "[9, Lemmas 8.3 & 8.4]".

Comment: And that would be `\cite[Lemmas 8.3 \& 8.4]{bibentry}`.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Some other question: In English, is the plural of Lemma indeed Lemmas? I am asking because I thought it has to be Lemmata.

Comment: @mathsstudentTUD According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(mathematics)), these two spellings are all acceptable.